# SQL Server setup hangs on install with SqlEngineConfigAction_install_startup_Cpu64

Tags: windows-7, installation, sql-server-2008

Formatted my PC and installed SQL Server 2008. Setup hangs as shown in attached image.

[image: install progress]

The top text reads:

> Running post-Windows Installer configuration timing actions

The bottom line says:

> SqlEngineConfigAction_install_startup_Cpu64

Installing on Window 7 64 bit OS. To install SQL Server SP1 is left to do due to this.

Comment: how much memory do you have for this machine? Have you had another instance of SQL Server installed on the same box (i.e. 2005 evaluation edition)?

Comment: @fergNab: No i have not any other instance installed. as i have formatteed pc this is first time i am installing SQL 08. Yes, i have installed Visual Studio 2010 before going for SQL 08. Thanks for the comment though!. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with SQL server and Visual Studio 2010. [Michael Campbell](http://www.devproconnections.com/author/1626/MichaelKCampbell.aspx) has a great article "[Why Can't SQL Server and Visual Studio Get Along?](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/visual-studio2/why-can-t-sql-server-and-visual-studio-get-along-)" that I think explains your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar issue with SQL server 2012 hanging and a workaround here:

http://public.madeinengland.co.nz/microsoft-sql-server-2012-installation-hangs/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This link does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting the `Configuration Manager Remote Control` service - it worked for me.

Comment: We’re looking for substantial answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.  To leave a friendly suggestion for an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Its right because it worked, your thirst for theory is honourable but surplus to requirement, people come here for solutions, not a thesis. I tried it because the UI said it was hung on a process that mentioned "configuration". If you feel working solutions are a waste of the Internet then go ahead and delete this answer, I was just trying to help, what are you trying to do?